# Saving information in HTML Tags / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want so save states of containers in any tags of them to use it with jQuery. The problem is JS says undefined if I use data-xy and data() or attr().

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Post some example code ?

Comment: Data attributes should work. Show us the code you're using, there's probably some issue with it.

Comment: I don't have any code with me I am selecting the right div with jquery because slidetoggle is working for example.

Comment: You need to come up with something that displays the incorrect behavior. Otherwise there's no way to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this a lot of times. the data attribute will be lowercase, always.

Say:

```
<div id="hello" data-testHello="HelloThere">Test</div>
```

The data will still be accessed by:

```
$('#hello').data("testhello"); rather than "testHello".
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with property as the id of div or element, and the value.

```
<div id="foo"><span>this is a test</span></div>
```

For set the state

```
var stateStore = {};
stateStore["foo"] = "dirty";
```

For access to the state

```
$("div").each(function(){
 MakeAnythingWithIt(this);
})

function MakeAnythingWithIt(theElement)
{
 var elementState = stateSore[$(theElement).attr("id")];
}
```

Another way is append an input type="hidden" with the state information